# How to convert my for-loop into a dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a beginner in python. I face a question that I can only figure it out by using general for loop. The question is

Using **dictionary comprehension** to create a multiplication table (up to number 12). Keys are strings of form "1 × 2" and values are the corresponding product of the two numbers. The first number in each key cannot be larger than the second number.

```
table={}
for i in range(1,13):
    for j in range(1,13):
        if i<j:
            product = i*j
            phrase = 'x'.join([str(i),str(j)])
            temp={(phrase,product)}
            table.update(temp)
            j+=1   
    i+=1
```

Ane the second one is Using function `filter()` to select the part of the multiplication table where one of the factors is either 11 or 12. Display the filtered result. But I can only select the keys out. I don't know how to display all the items within the table.

```
def factorset(a):
    return '12' in a or '11' in a

list(filter(factorset,table))
```

Comment: Hi Isabelle. You are asking 2 questions in a single post. Generally you would want to ask a single questions per post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From just translating your existing code to dict comprehension, I get

```py
multiplication_table = {f'{i}x{j}': i*j for i in range(1,13) for j in range(i,13)}
```

To do the filtering, you would need to do something tricky like this.

```py
dict(filter(lambda x: '11' in x[0] or '12' in x[0], multiplication_table.items()))
```

Lets break this code up, `multiplication_table.items()` returns a list of all items in the multiplication table as a tuple (eg. `[('1x12': 12), ... ]`).

The anonymous function
`lambda x: '11' in x[0] or '12' in x[0]` returns true if the string 11 or 12 is inlcuded in the first element of the tuple.

The filter applies this function to the list of tuples.

Comment: `multiplication_table = {f'{i}x{j}': i*j for i in range(1,13) for j in range(i,13)}` no need for `if` if you make the `j` range start at `i`.  Also, your test should have been `i <= j`.

Comment: Thank you very much！